# anchor tag disappear when print preview or printing in browser (IE, FF, Chrome)

Tags: html, printing

I need to print all the information seen in the page. The problem is the anchor tag is not showing its value when print preview or printing. I try to replace it using `<p>` tag and its working. The problem is, it should not be replace with `<p>` tag since it has a link that redirects to the detailed information. Anyone can help me about this problem?

Comment: More information is needed.  Can you please edit your question to include a relevant sample of the HTML that's not printing the way you expect, and more details about what exactly you want to see when printing it?

Answer (score -1):

add this in to your css

```
a:link:after,a:visited:after{content:"(" attr(href) ")";font-size:100%}
```

hope this will solve your issue.